# Xcode 4.2 and new Tabbed Application Project

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, tabbarcontroller

Can anyone help with Xcode 4.2 and the new tabbed application project? With Xcode 4.2, i create a new tabbed bar application, and it works as desired. However, it seems that instead of creating a new window and main.xib file that contains the tabviewcontroller, it sets everything in code within the appDelegate.

its easy to work with the tabbarcontroller via code and i have no problems setting up other tab items, however, i feel that my iOS development skills (they are new) are missing something as i would NOT even know if it was still possible to work with the tabviewcontroller graphically now in the way this project template has been setup.

Is there a way to work with the tabviewcontroller graphically? would i have to create a new main.xib file and link everything up to that? i'm still not strong enough in my skills to work out all the minute details but if that is the path that people suggest, i will look into it and try to figure it out.

I only want to work this out so i can fully understand whats going on now with Xcode 4.2, I have no unrelenting desire to only work with the tab bar controller graphically, but am curios as to why i cannot find it (or if i should)... just trying to get my head around how these things should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Single-View Application template.
HEre you can add graphically that control

Comment: Thanks for that. i will try and see how it goes. i have long progressed beyond that, but have done it using the xcode template (via code).. but will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: @MxnuelSalinas: You shouldn't avoid the questions by NOT using the Tabbed Application template.